# Concatenate matching on large data set

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been working on getting a script set up to do 2 things. First is to look for an identifying number and then searching for ALL matches and listing them in a concatenate. After figuring that part out, I built on top of it to create a UDF to then take those matches and list anything that matches. The UDF is below what I have.  There's 2 issues however, which I hope you might be able to help with.

The first being, it looks at ALL matches and returns a blank or a "," if I specify it. I want to just make it so it doesn't give anything unless a match is found.

Second, the file runs extremely slow. It's looking over 3 different spreadsheets, 2 of which are big files containing millions of cells worth of data. Do you know if there's a way to clean this file up to run more efficiently? It currently takes about 40-45 minutes to run (and that's just for finding 1 item, not the other 1000 I need to look up).

```
    Function DoubleLookUpConcat(ByVal SearchString As String, _
                      SearchRange As Range, _
                      ReturnRange As Range, _
                      SearchRange2 As Range, _
                      ReturnRange2 As Range, _
                      Optional Delimiter As String = " ", _
                      Optional MatchWhole As Boolean = True, _
                      Optional UniqueOnly As Boolean = False, _
                      Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False)

  Dim X As Long, CellVal As String, ReturnVal As String, Result As String

  If (SearchRange.Rows.Count > 1 And SearchRange.Columns.Count > 1) Or _
     (ReturnRange.Rows.Count > 1 And ReturnRange.Columns.Count > 1) Then
    DoubleLookUpConcat = CVErr(xlErrRef)
  Else
    If Not MatchCase Then SearchString = UCase(SearchString)
    For X = 1 To SearchRange.Count
      If MatchCase Then
        CellVal = SearchRange(X).Value
      Else
        CellVal = UCase(SearchRange(X).Value)
      End If
      ReturnVal = ReturnRange(X).Value
      ReturnVal2 = LookUpConcat(ReturnVal, SearchRange2, ReturnRange2, Delimiter, MatchWhole, UniqueOnly, MatchCase)

      If MatchWhole And CellVal = SearchString Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & _
                ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal2
      ElseIf Not MatchWhole And CellVal Like "*" & SearchString & "*" Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & _
                ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal2
      End If
Continue:
    Next

    DoubleLookUpConcat = Mid(Result, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
  End If

End Function

------------------------

Function LookUpConcat(ByVal SearchString As String, _
                      SearchRange As Range, _
                      ReturnRange As Range, _
                      Optional Delimiter As String = " ", _
                      Optional MatchWhole As Boolean = True, _
                      Optional UniqueOnly As Boolean = False, _
                      Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False)

  Dim X As Long, CellVal As String, ReturnVal As String, Result As String

  If (SearchRange.Rows.Count > 1 And SearchRange.Columns.Count > 1) Or _
     (ReturnRange.Rows.Count > 1 And ReturnRange.Columns.Count > 1) Then
    LookUpConcat = CVErr(xlErrRef)
  Else
    If Not MatchCase Then SearchString = UCase(SearchString)
    For X = 1 To SearchRange.Count
      If MatchCase Then
        CellVal = SearchRange(X).Value
      Else
        CellVal = UCase(SearchRange(X).Value)
      End If
      ReturnVal = ReturnRange(X).Value
      If MatchWhole And CellVal = SearchString Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & _
                ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal
      ElseIf Not MatchWhole And CellVal Like "*" & SearchString & "*" Then
        If UniqueOnly And InStr(Result & Delimiter, Delimiter & _
                ReturnVal & Delimiter) > 0 Then GoTo Continue
        Result = Result & Delimiter & ReturnVal
      End If
Continue:
    Next

    LookUpConcat = Mid(Result, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
  End If

End Function
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first image is the template I am working on Column B is the identifying number I need to reference to find the 1st set of matches. Column AC is ALL matches concatenated. Column AB is what I need to see (only the one's found on 2nd search).

The 2nd image is the report I use to find the identifying number in column B on the 1st image.  It corresponds to column K. It will find matches on column U to correspond with column B on 1st image.

3rd image is the last report I need to find if there is a match from column U with column A. If ANY matches in the original lookup is found, it will list it.

Comment: This question is begging for sample data with expected results. See [mcve] for strictures.

Comment: I put some images in that should hopefully help. I eliminated/hide the data that you do not need. ALL 3 images are separate reports. 1st image is the report template I am working on. 2nd image is a huge data file that contains the identifying number and all items. 3rd image is what there is a shortage of and needs to be identified. Hope that helps